# Which is the right version maven repository for geotools postgis?

Tags: geotools, maven

The [documentation](https://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/quickstart/maven.html) seems to indicate that the right maven repository to use is:

```
  <repository>
     <id>osgeo</id>
     <name>Open Source Geospatial Foundation Repository</name>
     <url>http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/</url>
  </repository>
```

However, it seems that the latest version on this repository was last updated in 2014. 
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.geotools.jdbc/gt-jdbc-postgis?repo=osgeo

On the other hand, the Boundless one seems to be carrying a much more updated version than the other repositories. This one was last updated in September 2018:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.geotools.jdbc/gt-jdbc-postgis/20.0

However, the documentation states that the Boundless repository is for snapshots.

Which is the proper version to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OSGeo repository is the correct one for stable builds (I'm not sure where mvnrepository.com gets its information from) - see http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/org/geotools/jdbc/gt-jdbc-postgis/20.0/ for the latest PostGIS jar.

### Update

Since the demise of Boundless the correct repository for snapshots is:

```
 <repository>
    <id>osgeo-snapshot</id>
    <name>OSGeo Snapshot Repository</name>
    <url>https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/snapshot/</url>
    <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
    <releases><enabled>false</enabled></releases>
  </repository>
```

This is all documented in the [Maven Quick start](https://docs.geotools.org/maintenance/userguide/tutorial/quickstart/maven.html) which is the minimum you should read before starting with GeoTools.

Comment: Thanks. Not sure why mvnrepository is not showing the latest one, or whether it is getting confused. It seems to be pointing to the right place. Usually it is quite reliable.

Answer (score 2):

I struggled a bit on the same issue since some, even recent, documentation is still reporting dead repository.

Below is the repository node I am using in my pom.xml file (of course I am talking about a Maven project)
Look at https://repo.boundlessgeo.com/main/org/geotools/gt-main/ to get the list of version supported by the Boundless repository.

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>osgeo</id>
        <name>Open Source Geospatial Foundation Repository</name>
        <url>http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <id>boundless</id>
        <name>Boundless Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo.boundlessgeo.com/main</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: It isn't valid anymore the URL https://repo.boundlessgeo.com/main/org/geotools/gt-main/

Answer (score 0):

The correct repo for Osgeo tools is
`https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/release/`

This was announced here https://www.osgeo.org/foundation-news/new-osgeo-repo/

As the [GeoTools documentation](https://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/welcome/upgrade.html) says, you should have the `pom.xml` like this:

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>osgeo</id>
    <name>OSGeo Release Repository</name>
    <url>https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/release/</url>
    <snapshots><enabled>false</enabled></snapshots>
    <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```